# Trim specific columns from specific sheets with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out how to trim leading and trailing spaces from columns **C:D** in sheets ending with **"_A"** and **"_B"** in their sheetnames.
So far, I have this:

```
Sub Trim()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Sheet.Name Like "*" & strSearch & "_A" Then
         Sheets(Sheet.Name).Trim
    End If
Next
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Sheet.Name Like "*" & strSearch & "_B" Then
         Sheets(Sheet.Name).Trim
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

but I don't know how to amend this to achieve the goal? Trim columns C:D in those sheets only.
Thanks

Comment: Do you know how much data is in your columns? You could loop through each cell in those columns, trimming them.  Have you been able to get any code for that part of the project? You'll just want to do something like `With Sheets(Sheet.Name) // For each cel in .Range("C:D") ...`

Comment: the number is not the same, but maximum is 1000 cells with values in each column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
Sheets(Sheet.Name).Trim
```

to this:

```
Sheet.Range("C1:D1000").Value = Sheet.Evaluate("INDEX(TRIM(C1:D1000),)")
```

Edited to put in your constraints as per your comment.

As @ChrisNeilson just pointed out, this will convert any formulas in column C and D to their values, removing the formula and making the results static.

Comment: Worth noting this will convert any Formulas to there trimmed current value

Comment: I don't have any formulas in those columns.
However, when i run the code, I get run time error 1004: application defined or object defined error. 
But when I run it using the previous edition, i.e. "C:D" instead of "C1:D1000", I don't get any errors. Why is that?

Comment: @Mpondomise oops my bad, I forgot to change `Columns(...` to `Range(...`. see edit.  You can certainly keep the full column reference, it will be slower than using a distinct range.